# TeamCity and wrong build.vcs.number.<vcs_id>

Tags: teamcity, versioning

I'm using the build.vcs.number. for versioning of my assemblies. However, last days I'm receiving the compilation error message:

"error CS0647: Error emitting 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute -- 'The version specified '3.2.0.66237' is invalid' "

I know there is a limitation of the assembly number to 65535. Is there a way to reset the counter or fix this issue in any way? I've tried to recreate the VCS in TeamCity but error still appears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally this counter is located in the General Settings page of the build configuration. You can just type a new value in that "Build counter" textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the build counter as the other answer suggests however have you considered using the `AssemblyProduct` attribute instead of `AssemblyVersion` which means you can put whatever you like into that field.

In our builds we put the build counter from TeamCity *and* the unique mercurial node id:

[image]

Presumably you have some script that updates AssemblyInfo.cs prior to the teamcity build to inject the TC build counter into the `AssemblyVersion` field so you will have to change this to the `AssemblyProduct` field